# How to use pagination on table using angular-ui

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

Here is my code. I tried it but it displays all the records and the pagination doesn't seem to work.

```
<div id="lead-casts" class="row" ng-show="showAllCast" width="auto" ng-init="getAllCast()">
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <h1 align="center">All Cast</h1>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <th align="center"><h4>NAME</h4></th>
        <th align="center"><h4>ROLE</h4></th>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="cast in allCast">
            <td>{{ cast.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ cast.role }}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <pagination total-items="totalItems" items-per-page="20" ng-model="currentPage"></pagination>
    <button class="btn btn-danger pull-left" ng-click="showCast()">Back</button>
    <button class="btn btn-info pull-right" ng-click="showCast()">Next</button>
</div>
```

I also tried on using limitTo filter on the ng-repeat but it only limits the display by 20 items.

```
<tr ng-repeat="cast in allCast | limitTo: 20">
```

How can I bind the records or ng-repeat to the pagination?

Answer (score 0):

use startFrom and limitTo 
here is the 
 `jsfiddle demo`http://jsfiddle.net/2ZzZB/56/